# Bundle only used modules of RxJS using rollup

Tags: rxjs5, rollupjs

I'm trying to bundle up a project with rollup that depends on RxJS (v5). What I'd like is for rollup to tree-shake and only include the RxJS modules I'm using.

I think I'm close, but it's leaving in the following from `system-observable`:

```
module.exports = require('./ponyfill')(global || window || undefined);
```

Sample repo is [here](https://github.com/martypdx/rollup-rxjs).

I'm currently using `npm i rxjs-es`, I know there are other rxjs installs, but I'm assuming that's the right one.

Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
const rollup = require( 'rollup' );
const nodeResolve = require( 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve' );
const commonjs = require( 'rollup-plugin-commonjs' );

// found this online, it does seem to correctly rewrite the rxjs paths
// but is it helping or hurting?
class RollupRx {

    constructor( options ){
        this.options = options;
    }

    resolveId( id ){
        if(id.startsWith('rxjs/')){
            return `${__dirname}/node_modules/rxjs-es/${id.replace('rxjs/', '')}.js`;
        }
    }
}

const rollupRx = config => new RollupRx( config );

rollup.rollup({
    entry: 'index.js',
    plugins: [
        rollupRx(),
        nodeResolve({ jsnext: true, main: true }),
    ]
}).then( bundle => {
    bundle.write({
        format: 'iife',
        dest: 'bundle.js'
    });
}).catch( err => console.error( err ) );
```

**UPDATE:** If I rewrite RxJS's sole dependency `symbol-observable` to be ES6 modules then it works.

Questions I have are:

- Should rollup (and some plugins/config) have handle the transition to grab a CJS dependecy? Or should a PR be made to `symbol-observable` to make es6?
- Is the custom plugin to rewrite `rxjs-es` import paths necessary? Or is there an existing plugin or config that would do this?

**UPDATE 2:** Looks like `symbol-observable` already did this about a week ago, but npm is installing older version. (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1785)